# Updating one of several variables depending on user input in python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, if-statement, optimization

I'm writing my first proper project in python outside of CodeWars katas and problem exercises in my book, and it is designed to calculate the total weekly volume per muscle group of an exercise program.

What I have written is a large dictionary called `bodypart` where `key` = exercise name (i.e. bench press) and `value` = primary muscle group (i.e. chest).

The program then asks users to enter an exercise and number of sets with the following code:

```
        # offer option to see valid inputs, then get exercise from user
        print('To see a list of possible exercises, enter "check".')
        exercise = input('What is your first exercise of the day? ')
        if exercise == 'check':
            print(bodypart)
            exercise = input('Please enter an exercise from the list. ')
        while exercise not in bodypart:
            exercise = input('Please enter an exercise from the list. ')
        add_to_part = bodypart.get(exercise)
        print('')

        # get the number of sets and check for valid input
        sets = input('How many sets will you do of this exercise? ')
        if not sets.isdigit:
            sets = input('Please enter a valid number.')
        sets = int(sets)
```

I created a count variable for each major body part, set at 0. What I then do next seems quite long winded and I feel like there must be a more optimal approach to doing so, but I am quite stuck on how to do it. What I do is add the number of sets the relevant counter based on the value in `bodypart`:

```
        # add sets to relevant counter
        if add_to_part == 'biceps':
            biceps += sets
        if add_to_part == 'triceps':
            triceps += sets
        if add_to_part == 'chest':
            chest += sets
        if add_to_part == 'shoulders':
            shoulders += sets
        if add_to_part == 'back':
            back += sets
        if add_to_part == 'quads':
            quads += sets
        if add_to_part == 'hams':
            hams += sets
        if add_to_part == 'glutes':
            glutes += sets
```

Is there a way in python that I can update the relevant variable based on the string stored in `bodypart` as a value, rather than using an `if` statement for each individual muscle group?

Comment: You can make `bodypart` a dictionary with key being name of the bodypart and value being count of sets

Comment: @Jay thank you so much! Just to clarify - create a new dictionary or append `bodypart` with eight new keys representing each main muscle group with starting values of `0`?

Comment: Yep, exactly, let me add some code

Comment: @Jay that is so helpful - thank you so much for taking the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to achieve the behavior you want

Here's a small code snippet -

```
bodypart_sets = {
    'biceps': 0,
    'triceps': 0,
    'chest': 0,
    'shoulders': 0,
    'back': 0,
    'quads': 0,
    'hams': 0,
    'glutes': 0
}
print(list(bodypart_sets.keys()))

add_to_part = 'chest' # dynamic string
if add_to_part in bodypart_sets:
    bodypart_sets[add_to_part] += 5

print(bodypart_sets['chest'])
print(bodypart_sets)
```

this prints -

```
['biceps', 'triceps', 'chest', 'shoulders', 'back', 'quads', 'hams', 'glutes']
5
{'biceps': 0, 'triceps': 0, 'chest': 5, 'shoulders': 0, 'back': 0, 'quads': 0, 'hams': 0, 'glutes': 0}
```